# Worklight Mobile Browser Simulator

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

The web browser always opens **Amazon Kindle Fire 2** device whenever i open android simulator in worklight to view my application in the web Browser.

[image]

Now i don't know how to change the default device **Amazon Kindle Fire 2** to some other device **Google Nexus 7**.What i want is when i click the android in worklight browser it opens with  **Amazon Kindle Fire 2** i want to change this to **Google Nexus 7**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ability does not exist. You can [suggest a feature request](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html).